# React display objects of an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have to display objects of an array in a react. I have done below code after searching on web. But it's not working. Can someone please help me where I am making mistake. Thanks in Advance!!

```
<div>
              {items.map((value, index) => {
              return (<div className="note" key = {index}>{value.title}</div>);
              })}
</div>
```

Comment: You should not use index as key, It is a bad practice.

Comment: @Amit That is only true if you can filter, sort or delete the list because a different value will get that key. If value has a unique id then prefer to use that instead.

Comment: Do you get any errors? As stated before; your code looks fine. Also `not working` is not the best description and the only valid answer to that is `you did something wrong`. What is it you expect and what is it you get? Did you use the dev tools to inspect the DOM or the React dev tools to inspect the components?

Comment: It was my mistake, I was using useEffect, it loads after page load and I was putting the content in a global variable. I should have put this in a State variable using useState. On State changing page reloads itself.

Answer (score 0):

The above implementation should work.
Unless you misspelled something.

`Note: react does not display values if they are null.`

Make sure **value.title** actually exits in the objects of the array.

Comment: items is not null and value.title exists in object array.

Comment: please add more code to your question so we can have a better picture

Comment: It was my mistake, I was using useEffect, it loads after page load and I was putting the content in a global variable. I should have put this in a State variable using useState. On State changing page reloads itself.

Answer (score -1):

Do the mapping outside of the render method, store the array in a variable and you can now display that variable inside the render method.

```
const list = items.map((value,index) => {
        return (<div key={index}>{value.title}</div>)           
})
render(){
    <div>{list}</div>
}
```

Comment: This is safer i guess

Comment: Index should not be used as key, Key should be unique to item

Comment: It was my mistake, I was using useEffect, it loads after page load and I was putting the content in a global variable. I should have put this in a State variable using useState. On State changing page reloads itself.

Comment: Amit, You are right. It creates issue for react to reload virtual-DOM. I solved this issue. But the above issue was happening due to this.